# How to join two tables and select max value with grouping

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to reconstruct the below query so that it improved the performance and time

Considering My tables are Recordings and Users

Recordings  table

```
bid | Date

1   | 02/10/2016 14:15:23
1   | 02/10/2016 10.30.15
1   | 02/09/2016 16.10.45
2   | 02/15/2016 14:15:23
2   | 01/10/2016 10.30.15
2   | 01/09/2016 16.10.45
```

Users table

```
id   | Udate               | Name

1    | 02/10/2016 15:15:23 | Bill
2    | 02/15/2016 14:15:23 | Max
```

My requirement is to join the 2 tables and

```
select max(date) from Recordings table group by bid with max(date)>udate

select distinct bid from Recordings ,users 
where Recordings.bid =users.id group by bid having max(date)>udate
```

Thanks

Comment: You say you "need to reconstruct the below query" (singularis), then you show us two different queries (pluralis). Is it  one or two queries?

Comment: Sorry the first was not meant to be query, I was trying to explain the condition, and by default it got treated as a query.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure with this, your purpose isn't objective.

```
SELECT bid, date , udate, name FROM Recordings
JOIN users on users.id = Recordings.bid
WHERE max(Recordings.udate) > users.date
GROUP BY bid
```

If you have more than 10000 changing records you can also pay attention on **RECOMPILE** hint

Comment: This will generate errors. columns in the select clause must be specified in the group by clause, and you can't use `max` in the where clause.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
SELECT id, uDate, name
FROM users
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT bId, MAX(Date) as uDate
    FROM Recordings 
    GROUP BY bId
) x ON id = bId
```

Comment: i have to check max(date)>udate condition as well.
And what is the difference between above query and my query : 
select distinct bid from Recordings ,users 
where Recordings.bid =users.id group by bid having max(date)>udate

Comment: Sorry, I mistakingly thought that the users table was the desired output. Can you add the desired output to your question?

Comment: Is this right usage, modified from your query to check max(date) is greater

SELECT id
FROM users
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT bid, MAX(Date) as uDate
    FROM Recordings 
    GROUP BY bId
) x ON id = bid where x.uDate>uDate

Comment: It's kinda hard to read code in the comments, but it seems ok to me.